# Why do I get an uncaught exception when implementing my own KVC setter/getter methods

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

My model classes are mostly implemented with synthesized setter/getter methods and everything was fine.  Everything was nicely hooked up to the user interface.  I later realized that changing one property should cause other properties to change (changing `type` might cause changes in `minA` and `maxA`) so I manually wrote setter/getter methods for the `type` property.  Code follows:

**QBElementType**

```
@interface QBElementType : NSObject
   @property NSRange minRange;
   @property NSRange maxRange;
@end

@implementation QBElementType
   @synthesize minRange;
   @synthesize maxRange;
@end
```

**QBElement**

```
@interface QBElement : QBElementType{
    QBElementType *_type;
}
  @property (weak) QBElementType *type;
  @property NSUInteger minA;
  @property NSUInteger maxA;
@end


@implementation QBElement
  @synthesize minA = _minA;
  @synthesize maxA = _maxA;

- (QBElementType*)type
{
    return _type;
}
- (void)setType:(QBElementType*)newType
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"type"];
    _type = newType;   // no need to bother with retain/release due to ARC.
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"type"];

    /* Having the following 4 lines commented out or not changes nothing to the error
    if (!NSLocationInRange(_minA, newType.minRange))
        self.minA = newType.minRange.location;
    if (!NSLocationInRange(_maxA, newType.maxRange))
        self.maxA = newType.maxRange.location;
    */
}
@end
```

**QUESTION**: Since then, whenever I change an Element's Type I get an *uncaught exception*:

> Cannot update for observer <NSTableBinder...> for the key path
>   "type.minRange" from <QBElement...>, most likely because the value for
>   the key "type" was changed without an appropriate KVO notification
>   being sent. Check KVO-Compliance of the QBElement class.

Is there something obvious I'm missing from [KVO-Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)?  Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly call `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` because your setter is named correctly. The calls to them will be added automatically through the magic of KVC/KVO's machinery. The problem may be that they're effectively being called twice.

Also, since it appears that `minA` and `maxA` are simply derived from the type, you can make them readonly and tell KVO to automatically notify observers that minA and maxA have changed any time `type` changes:

```
@interface QBElement : QBElementType{
    QBElementType *_type;
}
  @property (weak) QBElementType *type;
  @property (readonly) NSUInteger minA;
  @property (readonly) NSUInteger maxA;
@end

@implementation QBElement

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"minA"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"maxA"]) {
        keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObject:@"type"];
    }

    return keyPaths;
}

@synthesize type;

- (NSUInteger)minA
{
    return self.type.minRange.location;
}

- (NSUInteger)maxA
{
    return self.type.maxRange.location;
}

@end
```

Comment: I've tried running the app without `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChange....` but the user interface never got notified of the change!  (Side note: minA is a variable in its own right, it might not appear this way because I simplified the code for this question)

Comment: In that case, there's something else wrong. You really shouldn't need to call `willChange...` and `didChange...` in a setter like that. As for `minA` being a variable in its own right, understood, and in that case my suggestion won't work. However, perhaps you should post the full code, in case your simplification changes or removes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a manual setter does not mean you necessarily need to implement manual KVO notifications. You only absolutely need those if you're updating the backing ivar for a property without going through the setter. KVO will automatically replace your setters with versions that call the will/didChange methods before and after the "real" setter is called. If you want to call these yourself in your setter (e.g. you need more precise control over when they're called) you need to override the method [`+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCGIHJF) to return `NO` for your `type` key.

I assume the reason why you're getting an error right now is because the KVO machinery sees that you've called `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"type"]` twice in a row (once via KVO "magic", once manually) without calling `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"type"]`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can ditch the `willChangeValueForKey:`, `didChangeValueForKey:` calls and implement:

```
+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingMinA
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"type"];
}
```

Same for `minB`, of course.

Then make `minA` and `minB` read-only properties.

The different ways to do it are largely stylistic preferences, though.